# Most efficient way to handle different primitive types

Tags: c#, types, type-conversion, comparison

I am making a game which includes allowing the player to select different options and operations and then execute them to get true or false (and then do other things based on the outcome).

What I end up with (as the programmer) is two objects and a request to compare them in a certain way.

```
public object arg0;
public CompareType compareType;
public object arg1;
```

The args would be either an `int`, `float`, `string` or `bool`. Imagine `CompareType` being options like `GREATER_THAN`, `EQUALS`, `LESS_OR_EQUAL_THAN`, etc. As a default, incomparable types would convert to `string` and then compare (and probably come out false).

I have not been able to come up with a proper way of resolving these to get a `true` or `false` at the end of the comparison, without writing EVERY single possibility.

Is there a more generic way to convert types to the 'most similar one' other than casting and explicit conversions?

After that it would just be a switch based on the `CompareType`.

```
switch(compareType)
{ 
    case CompareTypes.EQUALS:
        return compare0 == compare1;

    case CompareTypes.GREATER_THAN: 
        return compare0 > compare1;

    case CompareTypes.LESS_OR_EQUAL_THAN: 
        return compare0 <= compare1;

    // etc.

    default:
        return false;
}
```

---

#### EDIT:

Thanks to all for the answers and comments.

For anyone who wants to know .This is the test program I came up with, based 99% on the best answer (had to change it a bit to work in online compiler):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        WriteResult("1", CompareType.Equals, 1);
        WriteResult(5, CompareType.Equals, 1);
        WriteResult("2", CompareType.Equals, 1);
        WriteResult("2", CompareType.GreaterThan, 1);
        WriteResult("2", CompareType.LessThan, 1);
        WriteResult(2, CompareType.GreaterThan, "1");
        WriteResult(2, CompareType.LessThan, "1");
        WriteResult("1", CompareType.Equals, "2");
        WriteResult(1, CompareType.Equals, 1.0f);
        WriteResult(1, CompareType.LessThan, 2.0f);
    }

    public static void WriteResult(IComparable left, CompareType compareType, IComparable right)
    {
        Comparison comparison = new Comparison(left, compareType, right);

        Console.WriteLine(left.GetType() + " " + left.ToString() + " - " + 
                          compareType.ToString() + " - " + 
                          right.GetType() + " " + right.ToString() + " = " + 
                          comparison.Excecute().ToString());
    }

    public class Comparison
    {
        public IComparable Left { get; set; }
        public CompareType CompareType { get; set; }
        public IComparable Right { get; set; }

        public Comparison(IComparable left, CompareType compareType, IComparable right) 
        {
            Left = left;
            CompareType = compareType;
            Right = right;
        }

        public bool Excecute()
        {
            switch (CompareType)
            {
                case CompareType.Equals:
                    return IsTypeMatch(Left, Right) ? Left.CompareTo(Right) == 0 : Left.ToString().Equals(Right.ToString());
                case CompareType.NotEquals:
                    return IsTypeMatch(Left, Right) ? Left.CompareTo(Right) != 0 : !Left.ToString().Equals(Right.ToString());
                case CompareType.GreaterThan:
                    return IsTypeMatch(Left, Right) ? Left.CompareTo(Right) != 0 : Left.ToString().CompareTo(Right.ToString()) > 0;
                case CompareType.LessThan:
                    return IsTypeMatch(Left, Right) ? Left.CompareTo(Right) != 0 : Left.ToString().CompareTo(Right.ToString()) < 0;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        //private bool IsTypeMatch => Left.GetType().Equals(Right.GetType());

        private bool IsTypeMatch(IComparable Left, IComparable Right) 
        {
            return Left.GetType().Equals(Right.GetType());
        }
    }
}

public enum CompareType
{
    Equals = 1,
    NotEquals = 2,
    GreaterThan = 3,
    LessThan = 4,
}
```

RESULT:

```
System.String 1 - Equals      - System.Int32  1 = True
System.Int32  5 - Equals      - System.Int32  1 = False
System.String 2 - Equals      - System.Int32  1 = False
System.String 2 - GreaterThan - System.Int32  1 = True
System.String 2 - LessThan    - System.Int32  1 = False
System.Int32  2 - GreaterThan - System.String 1 = True
System.Int32  2 - LessThan    - System.String 1 = False
System.String 1 - Equals      - System.String 2 = False
System.Int32  1 - Equals      - System.Single 1 = True
System.Int32  1 - LessThan    - System.Single 2 = True
```

I'm honestly not sure how a `string` `"2"` is greater than `string` `"1"`, but that's probably me not knowing something about how strings compare. Off to MSDN...

Comment: What is compare0 and compare1? The result of the converted arg0 and arg1?

Comment: `Convert`, `IComparable` and `Equals` would most likely help here.

Comment: compar0 and compare 1 would be the two variables to compare. Either string, int, float, etc. arg0 and arg1 basically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [IComparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface as parameter.

Example:

```
public class Comparison
{
    public IComparable Left { get; }
    public CompareType CompareType { get; }
    public IComparable Right { get; }

    public Comparison(IComparable left, CompareType compareType, IComparable right) 
    {
        Left = left;
        CompareType = compareType;
        Right = right;
    }

    public bool Excecute()
    {
        switch (CompareType)
        {
            case CompareType.Equals:
                return IsTypeMatch ? Left.CompareTo(Right) == 0 : Left.ToString().Equals(Right.ToString());
            case CompareType.NotEquals:
                return IsTypeMatch ? Left.CompareTo(Right) != 0 : !Left.ToString().Equals(Right.ToString());
            case CompareType.GreaterThan:
                return IsTypeMatch ? Left.CompareTo(Right) != 0 : Left.ToString().CompareTo(Right.ToString()) > 0;
            case CompareType.LessThan:
                return IsTypeMatch ? Left.CompareTo(Right) != 0 : Left.ToString().CompareTo(Right.ToString()) < 0;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    private bool IsTypeMatch => Left.GetType().Equals(Right.GetType());
}

public enum CompareType
{
    Equals = 1,
    NotEquals = 2,
    GreaterThan = 3,
    LessThan = 4,
}
```

This can be called as:

```
new Comparison("1", CompareType.Equals, 1).Excecute(); // returns true
```

and

```
new Comparison(2, CompareType.GreaterThan, 1).Excecute(); // returns true
```

etc...

Comment: Why you convert the args to string when you use Equals and NotEquals? Use `Left.CompareTo(Right)==0`

Comment: I like, except one thing: would just throw exc instead of returning false in the default

Comment: Tim Schmelter: In the question, D3Duck wants to: "As a default, incomparable types would convert to string and then compare".

Comment: Vladi Pavelka: Nicely spotted, edited with throwing exception in default.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question as to why you're using `ToString.Equals()` in the first two and `.Compare` in the second two.

Comment: Rufus, correct. I should use ToString() on all of them. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only considering primitive datatypes (which excludes strings since they are non-primitive), then you can always cast compare0 and compare1 to double and then do the comparison.

something like this:

```
switch(compareType)
{ 
case CompareTypes.EQUALS:
    return (double)compare0 == (double)compare1;

case CompareTypes.GREATER_THAN: 
    return (double)compare0 > (double)compare1;

case CompareTypes.LESS_OR_EQUAL_THAN: 
    return (double)compare0 <= (double)compare1;
// etc.
default:
    return false;
}
```

But if you need to include strings then I believe you should handle them separately. You can only do == or != with strings anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Try to overload operators.

[Overloadable operators (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators)